# Find direct link in a aspx form or read forms with android

Tags: java, android, asp.net, html

I daily visit [this](http://timeplan.uia.no/swsuiagrv/public/no/default.aspx) link to find my lectures at school. Every time I have to scroll down the list to find my own class, and then post it so I can view the result. Is there any way i could make a direct link to the preferred content? I'm looking to create a simple webview app in Android showing individual form categories.

EDIT : Really any method for converting the aspx info into another format would do the trick. Prefferably a direc link to each form item. But if I can convert every single item to a .xml file or anything else I could work with it. But I have to make it automated.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the outgoing request and write a simple application to POST the data back to the page. The [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class is useful for this.

Looking at the request in Chrome's developer tools, I see that the form posts back to itself and then redirects to the result page. Presumably, you should POST the form data to the initial page, which will then cause it to perform the redirect.

The form contains a large amount of ViewState data which may or may not need to be included in the request to make it work.

A completely different approach would be to find a browser extension, such as a macro recorder, which emulate your actions. [This plugin](http://www.addictivetips.com/internet-tips/macro-recorder-plugin-for-google-chrome/) (haven't tried it myself) appears to do exactly that.

Comment: Im a little confused here, ultimatly I'm thinking about writing a simple Android app for this purpose. I was thinking to use a WebView, with a direct link. Do you think this is possible? I guess I'm still a bit lost, would i be able to make a direct link? Macros, dont quiet cut it. In the second pharagrhap your talking about posting data? From a link? Or do you mean with the WebClient? (Sorry, if Im beeing stupid right now :) )

Comment: No problem. Since the site/question were tagged with ASP.Net, I gave you a c# solution. I'm sure there is an Android solution which is capable of programmatically building a request and sending it to the server to generate the correct page. Unfortunately I'm not an Android guy so I can't tell you exactly how to do that. Essentially, the URL which displays the list you want doesn't contain any parameters to tell it what to render. Therefore, you must recreate the POST which would come from the search page so that the results page knows what to display.